# Could someone please explain each piece of code to me I don't understand how it works

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

```
import random
import math

class Warrior:

    def __init__(self, name="Warrior", health=0, attkMax=0, blockMax=0):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.attkMax = attkMax
        self.blockMax = blockMax

    def attack(self):
        attkAmt = self.attkMax * (random.random() + .5)
        return attkAmt

    def block(self):
        blockAmt = self.blockMax * (random.random() + .5)

class Battle:

    def startFight(self, warrior1, warrior2):

        while True:
        if self.getAttackResult(warrior1, warrior2) == "Game Over":
            print ("Game Over")
            break
        elif self.getAttackResult(warrior2, warrior1) == "Game Over":
            print ("Game Over")
            break

    @staticmethod
    def getAttackResult(warriorA, warriorB):

    warriorAAttkAmt = warriorA.attack()

    warriorBBlockAmt = warriorB.block()

    damage_to_warriorB = math.ceil(warriorAAttkAmt - warriorBBlockAmt)

    warriorB.health = warriorB.health - damage_to_warriorB

    print ("{} attacks {} and deals {} damage".format(warriorA.name, warriorB.name, damage_to_warriorB))

    print ("{} is down to {} health".format(warriorB.name, warriorB.health))

    if warriorB.health <= 0:
        print("{} has died and {} is Victorious".format(warriorB.name, warriorA.name))
        return "Game Over"
    else:
        return "Fight Again"

def main():
    Sam = Warrior("Sam", 50, 20, 10)
    Paul = Warrior("Paul", 50, 20, 10)

    battle = Battle()

    battle.startFight(Sam, Paul)

main()
```

The code makes the two warriors 'Sam' and 'Paul' fight each other until one of their health's goes down to 0 or below 0 in an attack.
The code keeps looping until one warrior dies, but I don't understand how both warriors get turns, like how one attacks and then afterwards the other, and so on...
Could someone explain how the code to me? thank you

Comment: Please fix that indentation, this is invalid as far as Python code goes.

Comment: In general, this class of question is too broad to be welcome here. Try to break out a single, specific thing you don't understand, and generate some code that illustrates only that one thing.

Comment: (That said, the "how do they get turns?" follows from the `while` loop in `startFight()`, which -- contrary to its name -- doesn't just start the fight but drives it through completion).

Comment: sorry, could you explain how the turns work in this code?

Comment: Not easily, because I don't know what part of the `startFight` function's behavior you don't understand: If I explained, it would be in the same terms the code itself uses, so if the code doesn't make sense to you, I don't know how my explanation would make any more sense. Perhaps you could describe how you understand that function to operate now?

Comment: (BTW, correcting the indentation is pertinent and important here -- the way turns alternate only makes sense when one knows that both `getAttackResult` calls are inside whe `while True`, but right now they're shown as being at the same level instead of indented below it).

Comment: `while True` is an endless loop, so whatever's inside it will simply be repeated over and over. And what's inside it is `getAttackResult`, once with `warrior1` and `warrior2`, and then again with the roles reversed.

Answer (score 0):

From you question it sounds like you are confused on everything in the example code you provided.

For my answer I will focus on the most relevant portion of the code to your overly broad question.

Each part of the code plays its part in determining the winner however the `while` loop is the core of this program in regards to keeping everything going until a `game over` scenario is reached.

Step 1 of the while loop will first pit warrior1 aka Sam against warrior2 aka Paul by performing some initial math to determine how much attack Sam will do and how well Paul will block.

once that math is done the program will print out some statement to show who did what and if Pauls health is less than zero then the game is over if not then we move on to step 2 of the while statement.

Step 2 the code just flips the roles. Instead of Sam attacking it is now Paul attacking and Sam defending. The program runs the same math to determine the results of Paul attacking Sam and if Sam's HP drops below zero then the game is over and if not we go back to step 1 and start all over to see who/if someone wins the next round.

Once anyone wins then the game will print `Game Over` and the break line will stop the `while loop` and that is that.